# How to simulate throwing an exception only once in retry with JUnit/Mockito test?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I put a simple retry because the operation can rarely fail.  The simplified code is below.  The method `putObject` can accidentally throw an exception, in this case the retry should allow to invoke this method again.  Is it possible to write a JUnit test for this? 
I know that with Mockito library we can force to throw an Exception invoking a method but how to force this exception to be thrown only once?

```
public class RetryExample {
Bucket bucket = new Bucket();
static int INTERNAL_EXCEPTION_CODE = 100;
class AException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int statusCode;
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
}

class Bucket {
    public void putObject(String fileName, byte[] data) throws AException {
        System.out.println("PutObject=" + fileName + " data=" + data);
    }
}

public void process(String fileName, byte[] data) throws AException {
    try {
        retryOperation((f, d) -> bucket.putObject(f, d), fileName, data);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new AException("Failed to write data", ex);
    }
}

private <T, U> void retryOperation(BiConsumer<T, U> biConsumer, T t, U u) {
    int retries = 0;
    boolean retry = false;
    AException lastServiceException = null;
    do {
        try {
            biConsumer.accept(t, u);
        } catch (AException e) {
            lastServiceException = e;
            int statusCode = e.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == INTERNAL_EXCEPTION_CODE) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        retries++;
        if (retries >= 3) {
            retry = false;
        }
    } while (retry);
    if (lastServiceException != null) {
        throw lastServiceException;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class RetryExampleTest {
...
@Test
public void test() {
    RetryExample retryExample = new RetryExample();
    String fileName = "TestFile";
    byte[] data = simulatedPayload(10000);
    try {
        retryExample.process(fileName, data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Exception thrown=" + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [Mockito documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html) you can set different behavior for consecutive method calls.

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
    .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .thenReturn("foo");
```

In case of a void method you can do something similar ([Mockito documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/stubbing/Stubber.html))

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .doNothing()
    .when(mock).doSomething();
```

Comment: Great!  What if mock.someMethod void?

Comment: is it  .when(mock).doSomething() for void methods? (mock is in parentheses)

Comment: And doNothing instead of doReturn("foo")?

Comment: Good catch. I fixed the example.

Comment: still, when(mock.doSomething()) will not work, please see my note

Comment: Fixed it again :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a global data object to store the times of throw Exceptions, so in the Mockito library invoke the Exception method just taken the global data object to record the times. It would be simple. Just all by your control.